# Rabbitmq node.js amqplib client PRECONDITION-FAILED exception

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I've tried to assertQueue, *which I don't know what does it means in this context*, with many options.
but every time I got the same exception!

all what I want is to listen to some queues and start consuming the messages in those queues!
can I do that without being worry about whether the queue is durable or not?

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
var c_con, c_ch;
// *** code omitted  ***
...


var AMQPStats = require('amqp-stats');
var stats = new AMQPStats({
  // *** code omitted  ***
...
});

stats.queues(function(err, res, data){
    if (err) { 
      console.log(err); 
    } else {
      console.log('data received for ', data.length, ' queue.');

        data.forEach(function(queue){

            // c_ch.assertQueue(queue.name, {durable: queue.durable, auto_delete: queue.auto_delete});

            c_ch.assertQueue(queue.name);

            c_ch.consume(queue.name, function(msg) {
            // *** code omitted  ***
            ...
            });
        });

    }

});
```

```
Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED 
- inequivalent arg 'durable' for queue 'Servicex.0cc2f2711d7d42f1ae1c64e4e84e6092_handler' in vhost '/':
 received 'true' but current is 'false'"
```

Answer (score 1):

While the exception of assertQueue still exists, but I found that I don't need to run assertqueue before consuming .. so for now I just commented the assertQueue call. and consuming is working.

I don't know why all examples of ameplib run assertQueue before anything?!